# How do I extract a single digit from a string in a .txt file on CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tried Googling this but I didn't quite find a clear solution so I'm asking you.

I'm not sure how to put this but, let's say we have a `TEXTFile.txt` that contains a line of a string with random letters and numbers (like AJS12U3254FU8AD). Now, what I want to do is ask the user to enter a number with `set /p number=`, and then echo the digit/character from the string that this number represents. For instance (on the previous string example) if the user inputs number 3, I want the batch script to echo the letter `S`, if he inputs 4 to echo `1` and so on.

In my little experience, i think this problem comes down to echoing certain digits from a variable, like `echo %var:~0,1%`  but instead of using integer numbers to specify the digits, I want to insert the user's number in that process. Something like `echo %var:~0,%number%%`.

Is that possible? Or is there any other way I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables (with the exception of command line arguments) in batch is wrapped around with `%`, so you can't write `%var:~0,%number%%` because the variable ends at the first `%` and results in syntax error

You need to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```bat
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (TEXTFile.txt) do set var=%%x
set /p number="Input number: "
echo !var:~%number%,1!
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 1 minute :/

Comment: @iNT if some answer helps you please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. And don't forget to upvote any good answers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had the line of text you want as a variable line, you could do something like

```bat
@echo off
set number=3
set line=AJS12U3254FU8AD

for /l %%i in (%number%,1,%number%) do (
    call set character=%%line:~%%i,1%%
)
echo %character%
```

Answer (score 1):

A different method to force delayed expansion (which doesn't conflict with exclamation marks in the variable) is using a pseudo call.

- The call forces another parsing of the line.
- The first pass resolves the `%number%` while the doubled `%%` are reduced to a single one.
- The second pass resolves the now single `%`.

```bat
@Echo off
Set "var=AJS12U3254FU8AD"
set /p "number=Enter a number:"
Call echo %%var:~%number%,1%%
```